# HTML5 drag-and-drop inner children

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

Simple question, when enabling an element with DnD, if you have an inner child (such as a font-awesome element), it seems you can't drag the parent element if you click the inner. This means when dragging elements the user has to click the padding around the child.

Here's my element:

```
<a id="dragme" draggable="true"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
```

The following demonstrates the glitchy behavior when dragging. Try and drag when your click is on the icon itself. I'm using Firefox latest, not sure if the same behavior occurs on other browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/v6e5V/1/

Any tips on working around this such that the whole element is draggable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the children element(s) which will do the following:

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6e5V/2/).

Comment: Bosh, nice one Marcus. Have a big green tick.